# Modify text in columns using linux commands

Tags: linux, text, text-files

I have a tab delimited file with columns as shown below.

```
 chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic;exonic   KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV;nonsynonymous SNV
```

I want to delete text after ";" in columns 6 and 9. The output should look like:

```
chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic  KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV
```

Could someone give a linux command to solve this. It should delete everything after ";" only in the specified columns.

Comment: `sed` or `awk` are pretty much designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/;[^\t]\+//g' your-log-file > new-file-name
```

This means "delete everything after a semicolon up to (but not including) the next tab". The output will go to `new-file-name`. If you want to edit `your-log-file` in-place (once you are sure the command works the way you want it to, you can do the following:

```
sed -i 's/;[^\t]\+//g' your-log-file
```

You can also use `awk`, although I am less familiar with that program. Here is a brief overview: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-delete-word-using-sed-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/.

Comment: thanks for your time. unfortunately, the above sed command is not doing the task.

Comment: I am using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` on `GNU bash, version 4.3.30` (on Arch Linux). What versions of things are you using?

Comment: im using it on mac os. The command runs without any error but the output remains unchanged.

Comment: Try removing the backslash before the `+`.

Comment: Hi, i tried removing backslash before +, but no luck. the output remains to be same.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the output remains unchanged? `sed` will not modify your file unless you give it the `-i` option. See the edit to the post.